# Can a replacement service panel be installed alongside the original for temporary use as a subpanel?

Tags: subpanel

We are about to start a major remodeling of our mobile home. This includes electrical because the way it is currently wired makes no sense and is probably unsafe and not up to code.

The current breaker box is a 200 amp, 20 space box with every space filled even though half of the house is on one circuit, so most of the breakers are useless or unknown. We want to install a new 200 amp panel with more spaces for the new circuits as we remodel. Eventually this will completely replace the one we have now.

Can we place the new box next to the current one and move the cable coming from the main box to the new one and use the current one as a subpanel until all the wiring is done? The main breaker is on a pole with the meter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if there is enough length on the feeder it is common to replace older panels and even use their box (guts removed and a metal cover as a gutter to make splices in so the wiring reaches the new box. If this is the home with #6 wiring I would be installing a new feeder making sure it will be allowed by the AHJ and the park.

Comment: You might mention de-bonding the neutral in the original panel. I assume that's important.

Comment: @isherwood with guts removed that is part of the process.

Comment: I don't think that's the intention. "As a sub-panel". To me that means leaving circuits intact temporarily.

Comment: @isherwood the statement that eventually they will completely replace the original panel is what I am answering and pros regularly use the old box as a aux wireway or gutter if you like and this saves $ over all. And everything’s updated.

Comment: I've done that myself, but I don't think that's what's being asked. OP is doing a _gradual_ replacement, and wants to leave some branch circuits in service in the old panel for a while.